# Have vc-revision-other-window delete the file it fetched

Tags: emacs, version-control, diff

When calling the `vc-revision-other-window` command (`Ctrl-X v ~`) in Emacs a revision is downloaded in the current working directory, which ends up polluting it. Is there a way to configure emacs so that the fetched revisions are stored somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at `vc-find-revision`, and found that it actually jumps through some hoops to put the revision in a file, and then opens that file.  So I thought that I could just short-circuit that:

```lisp
(defun vc-find-revision-in-temporary-buffer (rev)
  "Visit revision REV of the current file in another window.
The revision is showed in a temporary buffer; no file is written
to disk."
  (interactive
   (save-current-buffer
     (vc-ensure-vc-buffer)
     (list
      (vc-read-revision "Revision to visit (default is working revision): "
                        (list buffer-file-name)))))
  (let ((old-buffer-file-name (buffer-file-name)))
    (vc-ensure-vc-buffer)
    (when (string= rev "")
      (setq rev (vc-working-revision old-buffer-file-name)))
    (let ((new-buffer-name (vc-version-backup-file-name old-buffer-file-name rev)))
      (if (get-buffer new-buffer-name)
          (progn
            (message "Switching to existing buffer `%s'" new-buffer-name)
            (switch-to-buffer-other-window new-buffer-name))
        (let ((new-buffer (get-buffer-create new-buffer-name)))
          (vc-call find-revision old-buffer-file-name rev new-buffer)
          (switch-to-buffer-other-window new-buffer))))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((buffer-file-name old-buffer-file-name))
      (normal-mode))))
```

I made this answer community wiki. Improvements welcome!